# Retrieve value from external link

Tags: jquery, json, get

I'm kind of familiar with both jQuery and JSON but I don't know if the following is possible:
I built a gmail contextual gadget that takes the sender's email address and retrieves a URL from our accounting software that displays at the bottom of the relevant email.

Is it possible to use either method to scan another webpage from our accounting software, find a matching email address, and pull in the internal ID via the link of the email address on the page?

It wouldn't be in JSON format so not sure if I could still manage to get that to work. So is it possible to get jquery to scan an external link like that to retrieve data?

Relevant gadget code to grab the email address:

```
    var matches = google.contentmatch.getContentMatches();
```

SAMPLE HTML FROM THE EXTERNAL LINK TO SCAN

```
        <tr id="row1">
        <td valign="top" style="" class="listtexthlctr">
        </td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="" style="" class="listtexthlctr">Edit</td>
        <td valign="top" style="" class="listtexthlrt">46477
        </td>
        <td valign="top" nowrap="" style="" class="listtexthl">test@gmail.com
        </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: 2 things - 1) finish the question/description of your posts' title. 2) provide some sample code that makes this possible to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $.ajax to retrieve the external link, get the HTML string from it, and scan for whatever string you're looking for (possibly using a regex if you're searching for well-formatted results such as an email address).